# Return HTTPS response from "data:text/javascript" for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, uri

I'm making an extension in chrome which captures a webrequests from my site and makes some modifications to the javascript source as per the user needs and then returns the results

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function (details) {
    if (details.url.includes(param)) {
        doChanges();
        return { redirectUrl:  "data:text/javascript," +encodeURIComponent(code);};
    }
},
{ urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
["blocking"]);
```

the "code" variable here is the modified code.
But when i run this, chrome is sending an error that mixed content is being loaded, and ends the request. 
So is there any way i could bypass this or maybe try a different approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Idea: store that code in your extension's `somefile.js` and expose it via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), and use chrome.runtime.getURL('somefile.js') as `redirectUrl`.

Comment: aren't there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: i just need to make some alterations..i wouldn't want to bother the user to update my extension every time i'm making changes to my original code